# How to sort LinkedHashMap by values in Kotlin?

Tags: sorting, kotlin

To sort by keys I can use

```
map.toSortedMap()
```

But what is the best way to sort LinkedHashMap by values in Kotlin?

Comment: you should implements your own `Map`, otherwise you can't guarantee the order after subsequent `put`s. and the `SortedMap` only support  [Key](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/SortedMap.html#comparator--).

Answer (score 62, accepted):

```
map.toList()
    .sortedBy { (key, value) -> value }
    .toMap()
```

Comment: If you need to use a function for comparison.
map.toList()
    .sortedBy { (key, value) -> function(value) }
    .toMap()

Answer (score 9):

You can use `sortedBy` with destructuring syntax and leave the first argument blank:

```
map.toList().sortedBy { (_, value) -> value }.toMap()
```

or you can do it without destructuring syntax (as mentioned by [aksh1618](https://stackoverflow.com/users/6346531/aksh1618) in the comments):

```
map.toList().sortedBy { it.second }.toMap()
```

and if you want to iterate the result right away, you don't even need `toMap()`:

```
map.toList()
    .sortedBy { it.second }
    .forEach { (key, value) -> /* ... */ }
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't why you have accepted the complicated answer.

```
var mapImmutable = mapOf<Int, Int>(1 to 11, 2 to 22, 3 to 33)

println(mapImmutable.toSortedMap(compareByDescending { mapImmutable[it] })) //{3=33, 2=22, 1=11}
```

`mapImmutable[it]` is the value
just pass it to `compareBy` function

Comment: This removes all entries where the `value` is equal.

Comment: `toSortedMap` only exists on the JVM

Comment: I would say your example is very dangerous while you have put a lot of assumptions in it. There is nothing in the question hinting about the keys and values being of the same type (`Int` in your example). Nor is it necessarily true that when a key is greater than the other, then also the corresponding value will be greater (key: 2 > 1 == value: 22 > 11). Last, but absolutely not least: The API's you use will sort on key (the `it` in your example), not on value, which is what OP was explicitly asking for. The accepted answer meets all these requirements.

Comment: This doesn't by values as requested; it sorts by keys.

Answer (score 0):

Considering a Map<Key, Value> object, we can sort by Value **if the map is defined in a variable** in order to insert it on the predicate:

```
val map = list                                 // List<String>
            .groupingBy { it }
            .eachCount()                       // Creates a Map<String, Int> where the Value is the count of repeated Keys.
map.toSortedMap(compareBy<String> { map[it] }.thenBy { it }) // Must have the Key type (String) in the comparator
```

Other combinations we can do with a Map<String, Int> object:

**Value and Key Ascending**

```
map.toSortedMap(compareBy<String> { map[it] }.thenBy { it })
// The Comparator argument's order matters!
// It is sorted by Value first (map[it]) and then by Key (it)
```

**Value and Key Descending**

```
map.toSortedMap(compareByDescending<String> { map[it] }.thenByDescending { it })
```

**Value Descending and Key Ascending**

```
map.toSortedMap(compareByDescending<String> { map[it] }.thenBy { it })
```